# Is there a way to parallelize this kind of code and save the output?

Tags: parallel-processing

I'm still trying to parallelize this kind of code with multiple variable input in a function datacube. The function is just 'do_something' involving multiple variables.

```
def datacube(x,y,z):
    xt = do_something with x,y,z
    return xt
```

In my main program I have something like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import data

x = y = 5
z_range = np.arange(3,300,3)

ans = []
for z in z_range:
    result = data.datacube(x, y, z)
    ans.append(result)
```

I've tried something like this to parallelize the code but it doesn't work.

```
dump = []
data3 = [mp.Process(target=datacube, args=(x,y,z)) for z in z_range]
dump.append(data3)
```

Is there any way to parallelize the for loop code?

Comment: The *"answer"* is a list, I presume. You can't have multiple threads appending to the same list, so I guess you either want each thread to return its own list and combine them at the end, or allocate space for the entire answer and rather than appending each one to the end, place it in the results array... but I am a Python beginner.

Comment: Me too. I started about a month ago.